# using wildcard in the dir locations and find all files with an extension

Tags: perl

```
my @hex_locations = ("$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-fsm9900_cdp-full/build-target/gnss-1.0.0",
                     "$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-fsm9900_cdp-base/build-target/gnss-1.0.0");
```

instead of these 2 lines, can I specify it in single line with a wildcard as below?
"$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-fsm9900_cdp-*/build-target/gnss-1.0.0"

```
my @hex_dep_files;

sub find_dep_files {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;
    if ($F =~ /.d$/ ) {
        push(@hex_dep_files,$F)
    }
}

for my $loc (@hex_locations) {
   find({ wanted => \&find_dep_files, no_chdir=>1}, $loc);
}
```

with above for loop, I am getting all the *.d files from the @hex_locations, can I do it in single function instead of calling a separate function called "find_dep_files", I don't want to call a different function from this for loop so I need not define the array @hex_dep_files as global.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question.

```
my @hex_dep_files;
for my $loc (@hex_locations) {
   find({
      no_chdir => 1,
      wanted => sub {
         my $F = $File::Find::name;
         return if $F !~ /.d$/;
         push @hex_dep_files, $F;
      },
   }, $loc);
}
```

or

```
my @hex_dep_files;
find({
   no_chdir => 1,
   wanted => sub {
      my $F = $File::Find::name;
      return if $F !~ /.d$/;
      push @hex_dep_files, $F;
   },
}, @hex_locations);
```

Comment: this helps for the second question, any clue to my first question? thanks.

Comment: Of course you can specify the directories using any language you want.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @files = </path/to/files/*.extension>;
```

Comment: I am trying to use the wild card in the directory name, like  $FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-fsm9900_cdp-*/build-target/gnss-1.0.0